# Using node.js to decrypt data encrypted using c#

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rijndael

I'm facing a issue now which need you guys help.

I use c# to do some encryption. Then need to use node.js to decry-pt it. But I just found that I can't do it correctly base on my c# encryption algorithm. If you guys have any solution, please help me.

Here is my c# encryption code:

```
public static string Encrypt(string text, String password, string salt, string hashAlgorithm, int passwordIterations, string initialVector, int keySize)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        return "";

    var initialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initialVector);
    var saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
    var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    var derivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations);
    var keyBytes = derivedPassword.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = null;
    using (var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initialVectorBytes))
    {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                cipherTextBytes = memStream.ToArray();
                memStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    symmetricKey.Clear();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}
public static string Decrypt(string text, String password, string salt, string hashAlgorithm, int passwordIterations, string initialVector, int keySize)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        return "";

    var initialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initialVector);
    var saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
    var cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
    var derivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations);
    var keyBytes = derivedPassword.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    var plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
    var byteCount = 0;
    using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initialVectorBytes))
    {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {

                byteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                memStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    symmetricKey.Clear();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, byteCount);    
}
```

If anyone can give me a same function for nodejs, that's will be really help. Anyway, thanks  for read this post.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. This is why you should follow convention and not use `UpperCase` variables names.

Comment: had to clean that up @JonathonReinhart, too painful :)

Comment: sorry guys, I will make sure clean next time for sure. Thanks for clean my code.

Comment: Have you tried using [the `crypto` module](http://www.nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)?

Comment: yes I do.I have try this:`crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keySize / 8, function(err, key) { var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, initialVector); var dec = decipher.update(text, 'base64', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8'); });` not working, and I found there is a "hashAlgorithm" I have used in c#, but not in Node. Any comments?

Comment: Your c# encryption is questionable at best, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` (pbkdf2) should be used instead PasswordDeriveBytes (pbkdf1). `Encoding .ASCII` can only represent 7 bit chars so you are likely to run into trouble at some point there. If you are stuck with the c#, then try to take in account those issues into account in your javascript, if you aren't stuck, start from better c# sample code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/637783

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that PasswordDeriveBytes does not implement pbkdf2 but a **modified** version of pbkdf1 (PKCS #5 v2.1). See this
[what-is-the-algorithm-behind-passwordderivebytes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22271/what-is-the-algorithm-behind-passwordderivebytes?newreg=8a9984326ccb41008c2bf51fae72bd9b)
for more information.

Note: The defaults of the PasswordDeriveBytes constructor are iterations = 100 and hashAlgorithm = "sha1"

Here is my approach to implement this algorithm in javascript/typescript:

```js
export function deriveBytesFromPassword(password: string, salt: Buffer, iterations: number, hashAlgorithm: string, keyLength: number) {
    if (keyLength < 1) throw new Error("keyLength must be greater than 1")
    if (iterations < 2) throw new Error("iterations must be greater than 2")

    const passwordWithSalt = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(password, "utf-8"), salt])
    const hashMissingLastIteration = hashKeyNTimes(passwordWithSalt, iterations - 1, hashAlgorithm)
    let result = hashKeyNTimes(hashMissingLastIteration, 1, hashAlgorithm)
    result = extendResultIfNeeded(result, keyLength, hashMissingLastIteration, hashAlgorithm)

    return result.slice(0, keyLength)
}

function hashKeyNTimes(key: Buffer, times: number, hashAlgorithm: string): Buffer {
    let result = key
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        result = crypto.createHash(hashAlgorithm).update(result).digest()
    }
    return result
}

function extendResultIfNeeded(result: Buffer, keyLength: number, hashMissingLastIteration: Buffer, hashAlgorithm: string): Buffer {
    let counter = 1
    while (result.length < keyLength) {
        result = Buffer.concat([result, calculateSpecialMicrosoftHash(hashMissingLastIteration, counter, hashAlgorithm)])
        counter++
    }
    return result
}

function calculateSpecialMicrosoftHash(hashMissingLastIteration: Buffer, counter: number, hashAlgorithm: string): Buffer {
    // Here comes the magic: Convert an integer that increases from call to call to a string
    // and convert that string to utf-8 bytes. These bytes are than used to slightly modify a given base-hash.
    // The modified hash is than piped through the hash algorithm.
    // Note: The PasswordDeriveBytes algorithm converts each character to utf-16 and then drops the second byte.
    const prefixCalculatedByCounter = Buffer.from(counter.toString(), "utf-8")
    const inputForAdditionalHashIteration = Buffer.concat([prefixCalculatedByCounter, hashMissingLastIteration])
    return crypto.createHash(hashAlgorithm).update(inputForAdditionalHashIteration).digest()
}
```

Comment: This was super helpful! I compared the output of deriveBytesFromPassword(password, salt, 100, 'sha1', 32) to the C# output from PasswordDeriveBytes.GetBytes() and the byte values match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

First, we'll do the `PasswordDeriveBytes` function with Node.js. This is [`crypto.pbkdf2`](http://www.nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_callback):

```
// assumes HMAC-SHA1
crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keySize / 8, function(err, key) {
    if(err) /* handle error */
    // ...
});
```

Next, use [`crypto.createDecipheriv`](http://www.nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv) to create a decryptor:

```
// find algorithm from the available ciphers; see crypto.getCiphers()
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(/* algorithm */, key, initialVector);
```

Then use `decipher.update` and `decipher.final` to feed it the data. They will return portions of decrypted data to you.

Comment: I have try this:`crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keySize / 8, function(err, key) {

      var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, initialVector);

      var dec = decipher.update(text, 'base64', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
  });` not working, and I found there is a "hashAlgorithm" I have used in c#, but not in Node. Any comments?

Comment: @Zhe: For PBKDF2, Node.js only supports HMAC-SHA1.

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same scenario I was able to get to a successful "C# encrypt => Node decrypt" solution using the code provided by @icktoofay above, **but** with the **PasswordDeriveBytes** replaced with **Rfc2898DeriveBytes**

My code is roughly:

C#

```
private byte[] saltBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);

public string Encrypt<T>(string value, string password) where T: SymmetricAlgorithm, new() {
  byte[] valueBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

  byte[] encrypted = null;
  using (T cipher = new T()) {
    var db = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes);
    db.IterationCount = iterationsConst;
    var key = db.GetBytes(keySizeConst / 8);

    cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor(key, vectorBytes)) {
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
          cs.Write(valueBytes, 0, valueBytes.Length);
          cs.FlushFinalBlock();
          encrypted = ms.ToArray();
        }
      }
    }
    cipher.Clear();
  }
  return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var base64 = require('base64-js');
var algorithm = 'AES-256-CBC';

[...]

var saltBuffer = new Buffer(salt);
var passwordBuffer = new Buffer(password);

[...]

var encodedBuffer = new Buffer(base64.toByteArray(encryptedStringBase64Encoded));

crypto.pbkdf2(passwordBuffer, saltBuffer, iterations, keySize / 8, function(err, key) {
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  var dec = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(encodedBuffer), decipher.final()]);
  return dec;
});
```

and is actually a combination of a few examples I found on the Internet.

Because I had a problem with the Buffer's implementation of Base64 in some specific cases ('+' sign at the beginning of the encoded string), I used base64-js from https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js, which seems to work fine.